# Is it possible to make a frothy coffee without an espresso machine?

Tags: brewing-process, espresso-machine, foamed-milk

I'm a coffee lover and my day starts with coffee but as i moved in my house i lost the coffee machine so i wanted to know **how to make a perfect coffee without the machine?**

Comment: By frothy do you mean foamed milk?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the silky wet milk foam may be a problem if you cannot easily reach a steam wand. However, froth is quite easy. All you need to do is fill the milk texture with small air bubbles.

A nice tool to do this could be your French press. After preparing your coffee in a French-press, swiftly clean it and fill it with some milk. Pump the filter in and out for a while. This will inject small air bubbles inside the milk, so the milk quickly turns into textured froth. Then, you can use it as a topping for the previously brewed French-press coffee.

This is not exactly same as any espresso-based foamy beverage just like cappuccino. But, the result may resemble it.

[image: Frothy French-press]

Answer (score 1):

As Mayo mentioned above, it is not clear if you meant frothy espresso (with crema) or cappuccino/latte?

In the first case. The chepeast and most effective way to make smth like espresso with rich crema is a Bialetti Brikka (not any other moka pot). Brikka has a special crema (pressure) valve that help get full body taste and nice crema foam on top. Here you can find useful comparative photos: http://101coffeemachines.info/moka/brikka-vs-moka-express/

If you meant milk foam, than stand-alone milk frother/warmer will help. It's better to choose a magnetic driven frothers like DeLonghi EMF1 because it's easier to clean it. However cheaper are also OK.

However, in both cases I personally would consider buying cheap espresso machine. Old good Delonghi EC155/156 today costs about $70-80 for example. You will have a real pressure for espresso and for the steam.

Comment: +1 for the informative 101coffeemachines.info link